# How to Remove Log IDs from Log Data Description in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

I have a log data in form of a pandas dataframe. One column is a text description  (strings) that contains log ids in the form of the "blk_-NUMBER". One of the text description looks like this:

```
'Blocked NameSystem.addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.250.10.223:50010 is added to blk_-3435353464324 size 34535434'
```

I simply want to remove the "blk_-NUMBER" from that column and keep everything else there, like this:

```
'Blocked NameSystem.addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.250.10.223:50010 is added to size 34535434'
```

Please note that in "blk_-NUMBER", the "NUMBER" can take variable lengths.

Comment: Try series.str.replace("YOUR REGEX HERE", "", regex=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with re library as the following:

```
import re
s = 'Blocked NameSystem.addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.250.10.223:50010 is added to blk_-3435353464324 size 34535434'
result = re.sub(' blk_-[0-9]*','',s)
print result
```

Comment: I have had this ' blk_-[0-9]', without the star! Thanks a lot.